# How do I configure to start notebook in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I know we can configure that in this section below in `jupyter_notebook_config.py`, but what should be the correct code to put to start the notebook in Edge?

```
## Specify what command to use to invoke a web browser when opening the notebook.
#  If not specified, the default browser will be determined by the `webbrowser`
#  standard library module, which allows setting of the BROWSER environment
#  variable to override it.
# c.NotebookApp.browser = u'%windir%\explorer.exe shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge %s'
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'start microsoft-edge:%s'
```